# Fetching data from table 1 using table 2

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as follows:

phpvms_airports
[image: phpvms_airports]

phpvms_schedules
[image: phpvms_schedules]

Icao on the first table is a HUB I need to find destinations for each HUB in table 1, from table 2 and find their lat and lng in table 1. Now here is the query that I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT icao, arricao, lat, lng 
FROM phpvms_airports 
    LEFT JOIN phpvms_schedules ON icao = depicao 
WHERE hub = 1
```

And here is what I get:

[image: Results]

The problem is that I get lat, lng for the hubs instead of the destinations.
Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: I do not see the `lat & lng` anywhere other than the `lat & lng` of the HUB in the bit of your database you have shown us???? So where do you store the `lat & lng` of the actual Airports??? In a table you have not shown us I expect. **We are not clarevoyant**

Comment: Okay, I changed the first image. I store all lat, lngs in airports table

Comment: Please lable with table is `phpvms_airports` and which is `phpvms_schedules`

Comment: also the table layout view would be much more helpful than the data view

Comment: What would be helpful is a sqlfiddle with data not ridiculous pictures. This isn't kindergarten in here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT phpvms_schedules.depicao as hubIcao, phpvms_schedules.arricao as destinationIcao, phpvms_airports.lat, phpvms_airports.lng 
FROM phpvms_schedules
JOIN phpvms_airports ON phpvms_airports.icao = phpvms_schedules.arricao
ORDER BY hubIcao;
```

Comment: have you put the right tableNames wher I wrote destinationTable and the right columnNames where I wrote lat and lng ?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT icao, arricao, phpvms_airports.lat, phpvms_airports.lng FROM phpvms_airports LEFT JOIN phpvms_schedules ON icao = depicao WHERE hub = 1  

Like this?

Comment: lat & lng columns are in airports table only. I need to get arricao from schedules and find its lat & lng in airports.

Comment: Aaaah, I think I might have got Your qestion wrong. Supposedly the destinations are also airports. So what You want is to select 
all destinations for all airports and return the coordinates of these destinations from the airport table ... right?

Comment: The destinations are all airports which exists in airports table. I need to find all destinations for a HUB in schedules and find their coordinates in airports

Comment: This will lead to the hubIcao being named repeatedly which is ok when You deal with it in your application. I updated my answer to a way thta should work if I didn't put in typos

Comment: not sure, I dropped the DISTINCT. Please carefully check the table names and  column names I used, because they are partly guesses.

Comment: Ok I changed "phpvms_airports.latlng" to "phpvms_airports.lng" and it gives me the coordinates for the HUBs. I need coordinates for destinations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115991/discussion-between-max-and-parviz-khorraminejad).